trying to access local QDrant dashboard remotely
This is weird and I'm probably doing something wrong.
I've setup QDrant in a docker container running on a raspberry pi.  I'm able to SSH to the PI to do all of the work (ie install docker and then run docker compose, etc).
Everything appears to be running on the PI.
dashboard should be at http://localhost:6333/dashboard
The PI is names raspnode2.local so the URL from my workstation should be http://raspnode2.local/dashboard.
When I try from Microsoft Edge or Google Chrome I get ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE
When I try from Safari - it comes straight up.
what?  What am I doing wrong?  Which checkbox did I miss?
TIA
